# Ruby on Rails Order By Using Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I currently have an order by working on my Ruby on Rails application so that on the Bookings index a user can order their bookings by `show_date`. This is done through the following in the bookings_controller:

```
def index
   @bookings = Booking.joins(:showing).all.order(params.fetch(:sort, 'id asc'))
end
```

And the view code:

```
<form>
    Order by:
    <select name="sort">
        <option value="show_date ASC">Show Date (Oldest First)</option>
        <option value="show_date DESC">Show Date (Most Recent First)</option>
    </select>
    <button>
        Go
    </button>
</form>
```

But what I want to do is enable the user to order by the film's title as well as the show date. I have tried to do this with this code:

views/bookings/index.html.erb:

```
<form>
    Order by:
    <select name="sort">
        <option value="show_date ASC">Show Date (Oldest First)</option>
        <option value="show_date DESC">Show Date (Most Recent First)</option>
        <option value="title ASC">Film Title (A-Z)</option>
        <option value="title DESC">Film Title (Z-A)</option>
    </select>
    <button>
        Go
    </button>
</form>
```

And the bookings_controller:

```
def index
   @bookings = Booking.joins(:showing, :film).all.order(params.fetch(:sort, 'id asc'))
end
```

But this doesn't work and I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Bookings#index 

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: film: 
 SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings" INNER JOIN "showings" ON 
 "showings"."id" = "bookings"."showing_id"  ORDER BY film ASC
```

I think it is because their isn't an association between bookings and film.

Booking.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :showing
delegate :screen, to: :showing
```

Showing.rb:

```
belongs_to :film
has_many :bookings
belongs_to :screen
```

Film.rb:

```
has_many :showings
belongs_to :certificate
belongs_to :category
```

Comment: Try this: Booking.joins(showing: :film).whatever. That would likely solve the nested join issue.

Comment: Worked straight away! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Lol your response was quick. Was about to go to sleep. Goodnight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Booking.joins(showing: :film).whatever
```

. 
That would likely solve the nested join issue.